# How to run windows services into server

Tags: c#

I have been made a windows service.in which i have been added project installer.in the project installer we have 2 things one is serviceProcessInstaller1  & second is serviceInstaller1.i have been changed serviceProcessInstaller1 account property as Local system.it is running in my local system but now i want to install into my server.
i think i need to change its account setting but not sure.
so please help me for that.
thanx

Comment: Ask the wizard who turned you into a Windows service to turn you back to normal.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/how-can-i-hide-the-acceptance-rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're worrying that you can't use the Local System account on the server since it's not your computer (your local system)?

If so, you've got nothing to worry about, the Local System account is a standard named account in Windows, so if you install it on the server and tells it to use Local System, it will use the servers Local System account so should be fine.

Comment: If you understand correctly, you are a freaking genius communicator and your talents are wasted on programming.  You should be negotiating peace accords in war-torn countries or facilitating cross-discipline conversations within academia...